# Finding polygon order by westernmost neighborhood for each point

Tags: mysql, polygon

I use `ST_DISTANCE` for getting the nearest polygon for each point and it works like charm with this code:

```
$neighborhoods = $this->_em
    ->createQueryBuilder()
    ->select('Region')
    ->addSelect('ST_Distance(
                GeomFromText(\'POINT(' . $point . ')\'),
                Region.regionPolygon
            ) as distance')
    ->from($this->entityClass, 'Region')
    ->where('ST_Distance(
                GeomFromText(\'POINT(' . $point . ')\'),
                Region.regionPolygon
            ) > 0')
    ->getQuery()
    ->execute();
```

Now, I want to get the westernmost (or northernmost) neighborhood for each point. How can I do that?

Comment: If the PHP is irrelevant to solving this problem, consider removing it, and instead see http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: agree with @Strawberry there are people here with knowledge on geospatial queries but with absolutely no idea about this wired PHP ORM you seem to be using.

Comment: What have you researched? Please add that to your question.